# ListBoxDragDropTarget set Target

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, target

I want to allow a target for a `ListBoxDragDropTarget` ListBox.

The problem is that I have four `ListBox` but each pair can do a drop on another one, but no on the another one, I mean, 1 can drop on 2, 3 can drop on 4, but 3 can't drop on 2 or 1.

How can I do this?
help!

Answer (score 0):

RoutedEventArguments has [OriginalSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)  which you can use to check who originally generated that event then you can simply set the [DragEventArgs.Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.drageventargs.handled%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to `true` to end the Dragging.